# iPhone opens wrong app upon “app” link

Tags: iphone, applications

I get ads for Amazon in the Facebook app, which is fine with me. Until recently, tapping on the ad doesn’t open the Amazon app. Instead it opens the VeryFitPro app which is the app for my LifeBee smartwatch. I deleted VeryFitPro and that fixed the problem, and then when I reinstalled VeryFitPro, the problem returned. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Details: iPhone 8, iOS 15.2 or whatever is the latest as of today, December 25, 2021.

Comment: Did you try to delete and reinstall Amazon app ?

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I hadn't thought of it. So I just deleted Amazon. Facebook's behavior hasn't changed. This time around, I haven't given permission for Facebook to open VeryFitPro, but that's what it wants.